# How to authenticate user accessing my finatra rest api (Scala) with azure active directory

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, active-directory, azure-active-directory, finatra

I have a Scala rest service on Finatra and would like to authenticate users accessing my rest service using Azure Active Directory.

Currently, I can do a curl to get the access token:

```
curl -s -X POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant id/oauth2/token -d grant_type=password -d username=$username -d password=$pass  -d resource=$resID -d client_id=$id -d client_secret=$key
```

But it requires the user to pass his password as a parameter which is a security concern.

Is there a way to authenticate the user using Azure AD with taking in the password (I am pretty sure this is not possible) or asking him to sign in?

Comment: have you tried reading a book by popular novelist CURL MANUAL?

Comment: it not a curl question. I am asking for ways to authenticate user without him to do extra work and be secure too

Comment: why do I have downvotes on this question? can anybody help me understand? I am new to this so don't want this to happen again.

Comment: most likely because what you are asking about sounds like potentially common problem (the bigger the service you access, the more elementary thing you try to do (i.e. auth) the higher chance you spent insufficient time searching for the same problem discussed before. And newbies do that most often.

Comment: BTW I recommend you first read  **[how to ask perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)** too

Comment: I understand that but as the problem suggests I am trying to do azure ad oauth in scala using finatra rest service and there is no documentation/question at all for this. I really don't know how can I be even more specific. I'll go through the link. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to use your user and password to login Azure account. You had better create service principal to sign in your Azure account. Please refer to this link: [Use portal to create an Azure Active Directory application and service principal that can access resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal).

Also, you could use Azure CLI 2.0 to create this.

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name {appId} --password "{strong password}"
```

Example:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name shuiexample --password "Password012!!"
```

You could get result like below:

```
{
  "appId": "bca24913-026d-4020-b9f1-add600bf9045",
  "displayName": "shuiexample1234",
  "name": "http://shuiexample1234",
  "password": "*******",
  "tenant": "*******"
}
```

Sign in using the service principal.

```
APPID="bca24913-026d-4020-b9f1-add600bf9045"
PASSWORD="******"
TENANTID="*******"

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'client_id=$APPID&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=$PASSWORD&grant_type=client_credentials' 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANTID/oauth2/token'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but isn't this when your app is working as client-side app?. I want my app to as a server-side one. I have a separate rest API (in scala). Only users who have been authorized by ad can access my rest services. In this case, how will the user get clientID/secret. I hope it makes sense. Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: @YtSh91 You could give your users different clientID/secret. You could create multiple service principal.

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: I am trying to validate the access_token now. I know it is a JWT token but I am getting invalid signature. I am manually testing it on jwt.io

Comment: @YtSh91 You should use Graph API to manage your users, I update my answer.

Comment: @YtSh91 Do you solve this issue? Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: yes but I used a different approach for this. Thanks!